# Enum to select list. Change <option> tag value

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Symfony 1.4 in default generates list elements from MySQL enum like:

```
<option value="free">free</option>  
<option value="machine">machine</option>
```

What should I do to change option tag value?, ex:

```
<option value="free">Different value than free</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some code like this:

```
$choices = $this->getWidget('mywidget')->getChoices();
// supposing we know what needs to change...
$choices[1] = "new value";
// supposing we don't need other options/attributes
$this->setWidget('mywidget', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $choices)));
```